# Own R packages .onload issue. Failing when building package

Tags: r, github, package, onload

I am trying to install and load packages in R from my private repository on Github using RStudio.

I understand this is done using the .onLoad command in a file called zzz.R which sits in the /R folder of the package. So I tried this, and when I tried to build the package using roxygen::roxygenise(), Install and Restart to build the package in RStudio, I get the following error:

```
error: Failed to install 'repo-name' from GitHub:
```

...

```
repo-name.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
Error: loading failed
```

The code I am using in my zzz.R file is as follows:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  GitHubSettings = list(
    ## Github token for accessing yth
    git_token = "xxxx",
    quiet = TRUE,  ## If TRUE, suppress output.
    force = TRUE,  ## Force installation, even if the remote state has not changed since the previous install.
    upgrade = 'never'
  )

  devtools::install_github(
    repo = "my-package/my-repo",
    subdir = "repo-name",
    auth_token = GitHubSettings$git_token,
    ref   = "master",## this needs to be master when the package is finalised
    quiet = GitHubSettings$quiet,
    force = GitHubSettings$force,
    upgrade = GitHubSettings$upgrade
  )

  devtools::install_github(
    repo = "my-package2/my-repo2",
    subdir = "repo2-name",
    auth_token = GitHubSettings$git_token,
    ref   = "master",## this needs to be master when the package is finalised
    quiet = GitHubSettings$quiet,
    force = GitHubSettings$force,
    upgrade = GitHubSettings$upgrade
  )

  library(repo1)
  library(repo2)

}
```

I am using generic package names and repository names in this example.

I have also commented out one package as well as its respective library() for the package to determine if one or the other package is causing the failure. It happens for both packages together or separately.

Comment: The docs for `.onLoad` say that there should be no calls to `library` in the hook.  What I'd do is write a separate function to check for and if necessary install the extra packages, and put a call to it into your own functions where needed.

Comment: Thanks,I will try this method.